# EF linq - до breakpoint на return в debug(e) не доходит при рантайме

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

У меня есть кода, он неправильно написан, это я знаю, и затратно с точки зрения закачки в память. Но я хочу понять с точки зрения TPL почему на return plants breakpoint не срабатывает. Хотя List формируется и передается далее на в контроллер клиент.

```
public async Task<List<PlantsViewModel>> GetPlants()
{
    var plants = _context.Plants
        .Join(await _context.Saptransfer.ToListAsync(), plant => plant.PlantNumber, sap => sap.Plant,
        (plant, sap) => new
        {
            plant.PlantNumber,
            plant.Plant,
            plant.PlantManager,
            plant.District,
            plant.Area
        }).GroupBy(x => new
        {
            x.PlantNumber,
            x.Plant,
            x.PlantManager,
            x.District,
            x.Area
        }).ToList();

    **return plants.**
        Select(p => new PlantsViewModel
        {
            PlantID = p.Key.PlantNumber,
            PlantName = p.Key.Plant,
            PlantSupervisor = p.Key.PlantManager,
            DistrictName = p.Key.District,
            RegionName = p.Key.Area
        }).OrderBy(p => p.PlantName).ToList();
}
```

Спасибо всем

Comment: Не понимаю причины